# Flask app on Heroku gives error: TypeError: 'unicode' does not have the buffer interface

Tags: python, heroku, unicode

I have a flask app that I'm trying to deploy on Heroku.  It works perfectly under foreman but when I deploy it, my login procedure fails with the error:

TypeError: 'unicode' does not have the buffer interface

The line of code where the error occurs looks like this:
person = verify_email_password(email, request.form["xyzABC123"])

Googling around, I've seen a very recent (early june 2014) regression in setuptools that causes this error but I am not using setuptools.

Comment: Any solution discovered to this? I am having a similar issue on Heroku with Flask.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading Werkzeug to 0.9.6 (per this discussion: https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/flasky/issues/17) worked for me today.